# Carrierwave replace file after manipulate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am running a background task, need to convert image to jpeg and store it. I am using CarrierWave uploader. Here's the code

```
  task reformat_user: :environment do
    User.all.each do |u|
        u.avatar.manipulate! do |av|
        av.format('jpg')
        av
      end
    end
```

However I could find no option to replace user avatar with a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to replace user avatar with new, you just need to assign a new file to avatar

```
u.avatar = params[:file] # params[:file] contains the file uploaded by user from UI.
u.save!
```

**OR this way**

```
File.open('path_of_new_avatar') do |f|
  u.avatar = f
end
u.save!
```

I hope I understood your question correctly.